# Invariant measures can be determined by the iteration of the transformation

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $(M, \mathcal{B} , \mu)$ be a measure space and $f : M \to M$ be a measurable transformation. We say that the measure $\mu$ is invariant under $f$ if for every measurable set $ E \subset M$, 
$$\mu (E) = \mu (f^{-1}E).$$
There is a well-known theorem in ergodic theory which determine the invariant measures of $f$:

> **Theorem:** Let $ f : M \to M $ be a measurable transformation and $\mu$ be a measure on $M$. Then $f$ preserves $\mu$ if and only if  $$ \int \phi d\mu = \int \phi \circ f d\mu$$
>   for every $\mu$-integrable function $\phi : M \to \mathbb R$.

For the proof, see Proposition $1.1.1$ from [Foundations of Ergodic Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=vlRyCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=foundation+of+ergodic+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilkseQ8K3aAhVEZlAKHUzODcQQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=foundation%20of%20ergodic%20theory&f=false), by  Marcelo Viana and Krerley Oliveira. In the previous book, the authors have asked the following exercise:

> Prove that if $f : M \to M$ preserves a measure $\mu$ then, given any $k ≥ 2$,
>   the iterate $f^k$ also preserves $\mu$. Is the converse true?

The fact that $f^k$ for $k\ge 2$ preserves $\mu$ can be obtained by a simple induction from above theorem. For the converse, since $\mu$ is $f^2 $ and $f^3$-invariant, by the above theorem, for every $\mu$-integrable function $\phi : M \to \mathbb R$, $$ \int \phi d\mu = \int \phi \circ f^2 d\mu = \int \phi \circ f^3 d\mu.$$
Specially, for the function $ \phi \circ f : M \to \mathbb R$ we must have:
$$ \int \phi \circ f d\mu = \int (\phi \circ f)\circ f^2 d\mu = \int \phi \circ f^3 d\mu = \int \phi d\mu .$$ 
Again by above theorem, $\mu$ is $f$-invariant.

I have doubt about my solution, since I used only the assumption that $f^2$ and $f^3$ preserves $\mu$. Did i missed something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is not wrong.

However, the fact that each $f^k$ preserves $\mu$ follows immediately by the definition, you don't really need the theorem you cite.

Similarly, for the converse, you can just say that $\mu(f^{-1}E)=\mu(f^{-2}f^{-1}E)=\mu(f^{-3}E)=\mu(E)$.